# Why is this one an undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

In my book of c++ I just found a code where the book says there is an undefined behaviour.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( )
{
const char * a = "aaa";
char * b = const_cast<char *>(a);
cout << a << '\n' << b << '\n';
b[0] = 'b'; // here undef. behaviour 
cout << a << '\n' << b << '\n';
}
```

I don't understand why . Does anyone know it ?

Comment: Do you understand the nature of `const_cast` and what it's doing here?

Comment: String literals cannot be changed. This code attempts to modify a string literal. Therefore it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: In the same way as `const int i = 42; int& j = const_cast<int&>(i); j = 0;`

Comment: Short answer - because you modify constant data, you are only allowed to modify data after const cast when original data is not const.

Comment: If the book doesn't tell you why, it's not a very good book. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is a list of decent books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals are immutable, so they're supposed to be stored in variables of `const char *`, to prevent accidentally trying to change them. The `const_cast` removes this layer of protection, and then `b[0] = 'b';` is performing a write to it. Since it's still a string literal that it's pointing to, this write is undefined behavior.

Comment: Nit pick: string literals are `const char[N]`, not `const char *`

Comment: You could elaborate on the possible reasons. E.g. the compiler is allowed to reuse the string if another constant has the same text. The compiler could even produce code that generates the string, so there might not even be a memory location for the text. The text could be stored on read-only media.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I know of only one case where that's relevant, but it's a useful one: applying the `sizeof` operator on a string literal will yield a value one higher than its length.  This makes it possible to define a macro to declare something like `static struct { uint16_t lengh, char dat[sizeof ("" LITERAL "")]} NAME = {sizeof ("" LITERAL ""), LITERAL} NAME;`, though unfortunately that can only be done at statement level, not expression level.